# Is there a trigger for the gates that trigger when the kinesis pipe is full?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods, minecraft-tekkit

I recently had an exploding kinesis pipe and set up a mechanism to switch off power when there is too much of it. I use a plain Gate set to emit a redstone signal on "Full Energy". However it does not work as expected, it keeps switching back and forth instead of letting the power flow up to the point where the beam in the pipe goes red. What does this trigger do and is there a better method for what I am trying to achieve? (I am powering my assembly table laser with an energy bridge hooked up to low voltage solar arrays)

*Edit:*
And it exploded again... That's really weird as it should have cut the power. The setup is as follows:

```
SX-BKA

S = LV Solar Array  
X = BatBox  
- = Splitter  
B = Energy Bridge (+Consumer/Producer)  
K = Wooden & Golden Kinesis Pipe, Golden Kinesis pipe has Gate  
A = Assembly table
```

I have now set the Gate to "Full Energy", and hooked it to the Splitter. My expectation would be that the power is cut once the golden kinesis pipe reaches maximal energy (before it explodes) and cuts the power so I am safe. Instead, it cuts the power periodically and in the end it still explodes. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The gate you are attaching to the buildcraft pipe measures the states of machines adjacent to the pipe. In your example the machine is the Assembly table.

From the setup you have described the energy has nowhere to go once it has been converted to MJ (or RF depending on buildcraft version). Once Kinesis pipes fill up they explode so you need some way to use the excess energy.

You could store it by converting it back to EU, store it in an energy cell (requires thermal expansion / dynamics). A different option would be to consume the excess energy, refineries are quite energy hungry when converting oil to fuel.

Comment: So what you are saying is that "Full energy" actually measures the energy of the assembly table?

Comment: Yes. In general, gates are meant to be a way for the pipes to interact with blocks surrounding the pipes.